# Is there a way to access parent modules of an imported module object?

Tags: python, module, parent

I need to know if there is a way to access parent modules from submodules. If I import submodule:

```
from subprocess import types
```

I have `types` - is there some Python magic to get access to `subprocess` module from `types`? Something similar to this for classes `().__class__.__bases__[0].__subclasses__()`.

Comment: Your example is weird -- `types` is actually the standard Python `types` module.  Your import line will do the same as `import types`, and `types` will be exactly the same module object in both cases.

Comment: subprocess is not the "parent" of the `types` module in any sense that appears meaningful or useful to me. `subprocess` has evidently imported `types`, just like many other modules import `types`.  What are you trying to do?


What are you trying to do?

Comment: I know that types is standard module, but I found it in subprocess modules when I search for all submodules.

Comment: @John I try to block access to filesystem and the shell.

Comment: @jcubic If you've still got this project in production, please stop users having access to it. I'll break out of the sandbox you've made if it'll convince you. I can break out of a sandbox with no builtins whatsoever, where only literals are allowed.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 it was years ago that I learn this hard way, someone wipe out disk on my shared hosting. It was for my https://trypython.jcubic.pl/ I've needed to disable it but few years later I've found brython in js and now It use this library.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you've accessed a module you can typically get to it from the `sys.modules` dictionary.  Python doesn't keep "parent pointers" with names, particularly because the relationship is not one-to-one.  For example, using your example:

```
>>> from subprocess import types
>>> types
<module 'types' from '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/types.pyc'>
>>> import sys
>>> sys.modules['subprocess']
<module 'subprocess' from '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.pyc'>
```

If you'll note the presence of `types` in the `subprocess` module is just an artifact of the `import types` statement in it.  You just `import types` if you need that module.

In fact, a future version of `subprocess` may not import `types` any more, and your code will break.  You should only import the names that appear in the `__all__` list of a module; consider other names as implementation details.

So, for example:

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> dir(subprocess)
['CalledProcessError', 'MAXFD', 'PIPE', 'Popen', 'STDOUT', '_PIPE_BUF', '__all__', '__builtins__', '__doc__',
 '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '_active', '_cleanup', '_demo_posix', '_demo_windows', '_eintr_retry_call',
 '_has_poll', 'call', 'check_call', 'check_output', 'errno', 'fcntl', 'gc', 'list2cmdline', 'mswindows', 'os',
 'pickle', 'select', 'signal', 'sys', 'traceback', 'types']
>>> subprocess.__all__
['Popen', 'PIPE', 'STDOUT', 'call', 'check_call', 'check_output', 'CalledProcessError']
```

You can see that most of the names visible in `subprocess` are just other top-level modules that it imports.

Answer (score 5):

For posterity, I ran into this also and came up with the one liner:

```
import sys
parent_module = sys.modules['.'.join(__name__.split('.')[:-1]) or '__main__']
```

The `or '__main__'` part is just in case you load the file directly it will return itself.

Comment: This answers how to get the parent module from within a module ([asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77261423/python-import-the-actual-module-object-for-the-containing-package-without-nami/77266131#77266131)), but this question is about how to access e.g. the `subprocess` module given the imported `subprocess.types` module.

Answer (score 0):

```
full_module_name = module.__name__
parent, _, sub = full_module_name.rpartition('.')
if parent:
    parent = import(parent, fromlist='dummy')
```

Comment: This does not seem to work with the example given in the question, using both Python 3.9 and 2.7: `types.__name__` is just `'types'`, not `'subprocess.types'`, and `import(parent, fromlist='dummy')` is a syntax error.

Answer (score -1):

I assume you are not inside the subprocess module already, you could do

```
import somemodule
children = dir(somemodule)
```

Then you could inspect the children of subprocess with the inspect module:
http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html

Maybe the getmodule method would be useful for you?
http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html#inspect.getmodule

```
import inspect
parent_module = inspect.getmodule(somefunction)
children = dir(parent_module)
package = parent_module.__package__
```

On my machine __package__ returns empty for 'types', but can be more useful for my own modules as it does return the parent module as a string

Comment: @orangutancloud: But he's trying to pretend that he doesn't know that he just imported `types` from `subprocess` -- Given `types`, `subprocess` is the ANSWER that he's seeking, not the other way around.

Comment: @john good point, I tried to edit the answer to be more helpful. The inspect module in python is one of my favorite parts about the language.

Comment: @orangutancloud: `inspect.getmodule(types)` produces exactly the same as `types.__file__` (on my machine: `'C:\\python27\\lib\\types.pyc'`). How helpful or relevant is that?

Comment: On my machine it does actually return the module object, if you need the parent of a function this works well, if you need the parent module I just noticed the __package__ property which points to the parent module as a string like 'somepackage.module'

Comment: inspect.getmodule(types) <module 'types' from '/python2.6/types.pyc'>

Comment: @orangutancloud: Ermmm, I was wrong; it does return the actual module object. This is useless if you know already that it's a module, and it certainly is not a pointer to the parent as the OP defines it, and neither is `module.__package__`.

Comment: Yeah, it's not really that useful. This one is a bit tricky without a more specific use case, since types and subprocess are just examples. I think I am going to give up on this one.

Answer (score -1):

Best way that worked for us was:

Let's say folder structure

```
src
 |demoproject
 |
 |--> uimodule--> ui.py
 |--> backendmodule --> be.py
 setup.py
```

1. Create installable package out of the project
2. Have `__init__.py` in all the directory (module)
3. create setup.py (keep in top level folder, here inside src)

Sample

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

    setup(
        name="demopackage",
        version="1",
        packages=find_packages(exclude=["tests.*", "tests"]),
        author='',
        author_email='',
        description="",
        url="",
        )
```

4. From src folder, create installable package
   pip3 install .
5. this will install a package --> demopackage
6. Now from any of your module you can access any module, ex
7. from ui.py to access be.py function calldb(), make below import

```
from demopackage.backendmodule.be import calldb
```

8. and so on, when you a new folder into your project just add `__init__.py` in that folder and it will be accessible, just like above, but you have to execute `pip3 install .`

Comment: Sorry, this answer how to create a Python module not how to access the parent module from any module.

Comment: You can access the all module once you create a package, it's much cleaner, free from all those hacks of inserting paths in PYTHONPATH or system path..